# p:commandButton doesn't execute f:setPropertyActionListener in JSF 2

Tags: button, jsf-2, primefaces

I work with JSF2 and PrimeFaces and I want to go to another page with this button:

```
<p:column>
    <h:commandButton action="userCommand" value="list of commands" >
        <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{car}" target="#{userController.u1}" />  
    </h:commandButton>
</p:column>
```

On the target page I use some information from `userController.u1`, but the `<f:setPropertyActionListener>` tag doesn't seem to be executed.

I thus get the following exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

In response to Arjan, thank you for your detailed response, but I think there is another method to do this, instead of using a new managedBean as I did in my question, I use one (sessionScoped) that is already instantiated and then I called it in the new constructor to retrieve the value,

How do you find this solution? Can you help me to call the other managedBean from the constructor of the new managedBean?

Because I tested this :

```
  ELContext elContext = context.getELContext();
    Application application = context.getApplication();
    String userid = (String) application.evaluateValueExpressionGet(context,
            "#{userBean.userid}", String.class);
```

but I have a problem with "context". Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how you setup the corresponding navigation rule for `userCommand` and/or the scope of `userController` if this is going to work at all.

The action listener sets a value in the bean before navigation happens. If the navigation causes a redirect to happen, then the bean must be in a scope that's available after this redirect. Without having added any additional scopes, this would be the application scope and session scope.

If the bean was in request scope or view scope, your value would be set in the bean corresponding to the request before the redirect took place. After the redirect a new request to a new page is done, and hence a new request scope or new view scope starts. This means your value will be lost.

Using the application scope or session scope would theoretically fix this, but you would run into major problems if your application had multiple users (very likely) or if a single user has multiple windows/tabs open.

In case your navigation rule *does not* use a redirect, it should actually work. The problem now is that you'll be suffering from the "one URL behind problem": the address bar of the browser will still show the old page.

Since you're not really executing any action and just want to go to a new page, a better approach is to link directly to that page using an `<h:button>` or `<h:link>` and provide the If of said car as a parameter.

This will issue a GET request, which has the additional benefit of being bookmarkable. If you were doing the Post-Redirect thing, it will also initially perform better. On the target page, you do have to be prepared to convert the parameter back into the car instance. For this you can use the `<f:viewParam>` tag.

Example for linking:

```
<p:column>
    <h:button outcome="userCommand" value="list of commands">
        <f:param name="car_id" value="#{car.id}"/>
    </h:Button>
</p:column>
```

Example for target page:

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="car_id" value="#{userController.u1}" converter="#{carConverter}" />    
</f:metadata>
```

For a working example of this see [index.xhtml](http://code.google.com/p/javaee6-crud-example/source/browse/WebContent/index.xhtml?name=default) and [user_edit.xhtml](http://code.google.com/p/javaee6-crud-example/source/browse/WebContent/user_edit.xhtml?name=default) in [this](http://jdevelopment.nl/sample-crud-app-with-jsf-and-richfaces) example CRUD application.