# JSF 2.0 view scope not working

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I use PrimeFaces in my application, in which I have a data table populated with data. I also have one edit command button.

Now I would like to open a new JSF page. The action to do that is bound to a backing bean in view scope. In the action method I have access to the bean's values, but on the new JSF page I can't access any values of this bean anymore.

This is my code:

```xml
<p:commandLink title="Edit" id="editBtn" action="#{personRegisterController.selectPerson}">
    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{person}" target="#{personRegisterController.personBean}"/>
</p:commandLink>
```

Answer (score 4):

The view scope in JSF is the scope that entails only a single view (page). So, as long as you post-back to the same view, you'll retain the data of view scoped beans.

However, as soon as you navigate to a new view a new view scope starts. In other words, you cannot use the view scope to transfer data between views (between requests to different pages).

See this answer for one possible solution on how you can do this transferring: [p:commandButton doesn't execute f:setPropertyActionListener in JSF 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12025720/pcommandbutton-doesnt-execute-fsetpropertyactionlistener-in-jsf-2/12026496#12026496)

Incidentally, note that the `setPropertyActionListener` isn't necessary for what you're doing here. You can provide the data directly to your action method:

```xml
<p:commandLink action="#{personRegisterController.selectPerson(person)}"/>
```

Comment: i pass person in my selectPerson(person) method and get all value of person inside my method but how i get this person value in my editPerson.xthml page and tell me that i chage scope request or set it as view scope

Comment: @Piyush See this answer for one possible solution on how you can do this transferring: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12025720/pcommandbutton-doesnt-execute-fsetpropertyactionlistener-in-jsf-2/12026496#12026496